# Unable to use import instead of require, or unable to build dependensides with ts-node & tsdx

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm, ts-node, tsdx

I have the following problem and know exactly why it has been triggered, but I haven't found any solution yet, so probably the community may help me with that.

I am using `tsdx` for initiating ts repos, and also `ts-node` for quick debug (instead of building code each time).

#### Recursive Dilemma:

So, each time when I want to add the module to my package via `yarn add modulename` and if in my `tsconfig.json` file in `compilerOptions` option: `"module": "commonjs"` has the following value, `tsdx build` unable to build code, and return me the following error:

> *Error: Incompatible tsconfig option. Module resolves to 'CommonJS'. This is incompatible with rollup, please use 'module: "ES2015"' or 'module: "ESNext"'*

[image: module: "ES2015"]

**BUT!**

if I will update `compilerOptions` to `module: "ESNext"` from `commonjs`, `ts-node` will give me an error, because it's still unable to use `import {Method} from Module` instead of `const x = require(CommonJS)` (which is quite old bug, according to [this issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/935#issuecomment-579718641) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61568271/import-doesnt-work-with-module-esnext-in-tsconfig-json))
[image]

- Typescript -v 4.1.5 (latest)
- ts-node: "^9.1.1"
- node -v: 15+

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs", || "ESNext"
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    ...//other options
```

According to that, I am using WebStorm and [`README.md`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#intellij-and-webstorm) from ts-node repo, I understand, that I could update `Environment Variables` with custom tsconfig. *So in that case I need two tsconfig files in repo, for ts-node and for production*. So the question is: maybe there is another TS_NODE_FLAG, especially for `module` compiler options? So I could run ts-node with the flag, that would overwrite this minor parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently working compromise is having two config files, which are exactly the same:

- `tsconfig.json`
- `tsconfig.dev.json`

except that the second has `"module":"commonjs"`

[image: Compomise]

The second option, which actually somehow **not working for me** is adding to WebStrom's  Environment Variables `TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{"module":"commonjs"}'` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635956/overriding-tsconfig-json-for-ts-node-in-mocha).

Comment: I got the same problem

Comment: @Pumuckelo. Well, I don't have a more elegant way than having two `config` files. So if it helps you, or you think that this problem deserves more attention, you could upvote on the question or answer. *Depends, what's have more importance for you. Or write your own solution.*

Answer (score 2):

another option:

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
export default {
    ...
    plugins: [
        typescript({
            // 覆盖 tsconfig.json 的配置项
            tsconfigOverride: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    module: "ESNext"
                },
                include: ['src/**/*'],
            },
        })  
    ]
};
```